# Prolog | findall with result list of another findall

Tags: prolog

How can i get values by an specific condition, and next with these selected elements get values from other facts serie?

I've this code

```
%code, date, amount
values1('AAA', date(02, 03, 2020), 1000).
values1('AAA', date(31, 03, 2020), 2000).
values1('BBB', date(02, 04, 2020), 1350).
values1('BBB', date(15, 04, 2020), 1500).
values1('CCC', date(23, 05, 2020), 5500).
values1('CCC', date(01, 05, 2020), 750).
values1('DDD', date(06, 05, 2020), 3560).
values1('AAA', date(18, 06, 2020), 4600).
values1('CCC', date(27, 07, 2020), 1200).

%code, percent
values2('AAA', '0.2').
values2('BBB', '0.25').
values2('CCC', '0.55').
values2('DDD', '0.98').

predicate1(Code, Percent) :- 
    findall(Code, (values1(Code, _, Value), Value > 1000), Code),
    findall(Percent, values2(Code, Percent), Percent).
```

For example in this case the idea it's get Code which amount is bigger than 1000, and when there are selected get the percent from value2, but the Percent list it's return empty. Why it happening that?

This is the return

```
predicate1(Code, Percent).
Code = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'CCC'],
Percent = []
```

it may be by the difference between number of elements in list of Code and number of fact of values2 maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo and a (few) logic errors.

The value of `Code` goes into a list of `Code`: `CodeList`. You have variable `Code` on first and third position. Use this:

```
findall(Code, (values1(Code, _, Value), Value > 1000), CodeList).
```

Run it:

```
?- findall(Code, (values1(Code, _, Value), Value > 1000), CodeList).
CodeList = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'CCC'].
```

Duplicate elements are removed by using the predicate `setof/3` instead.

However, `setof/3` demands that you indicate ("existentially quantify" with the caret notation: `Value^Date^`) the variables that shall be invisible outside the inner goal, otherwise backtracking over possible values of `Value` and `Date` will occur outside of `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(Code, Value^Date^(values1(Code, Date, Value), Value > 1000), CodeList).
CodeList = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'].
```

Now you just need to "join" any "code" with the "percentage" ... inside of `setof/3`:

```
?- setof([Code,Percent], 
         Value^Date^(values1(Code, Date, Value),
                     Value > 1000,
                     values2(Code,Percent)),
         Set).

Set = [['AAA', '0.2'], ['BBB', '0.25'], ['CCC', '0.55'], ['DDD', '0.98']].
```

You can pack this into a predicate which backtracks over the `setof/3` result:

```
gimme(Code, Percent) :-
   setof([Code,Percent], 
            Value^Date^(values1(Code, Date, Value),
                        Value > 1000,
                        values2(Code,Percent)),
            Set),
   member([Code,Percent],Set).
```

Note that the reuse of variables of `Code` and `Percent` inside `setof/3` and in the call to `member/2` s well is actually ok: These are *not* the same variables.

And so:

```
?- gimme(Code,Percent).
Code = 'AAA',
Percent = '0.2' ;
Code = 'BBB',
Percent = '0.25' ;
Code = 'CCC',
Percent = '0.55' ;
Code = 'DDD',
Percent = '0.98'.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
predicate1(Code,Percent)
:-
values1(Code,_,Amount) ,
Amount > 1000 ,
values2(Code,Percent)
.
```

example usage from toplevel :

```
?- predicate1(Code,Percent).
Code = 'AAA',
Percent = '0.2' ;
Code = 'BBB',
Percent = '0.25' ;
Code = 'BBB',
Percent = '0.25' ;
Code = 'CCC',
Percent = '0.55' ;
Code = 'DDD',
Percent = '0.98' ;
Code = 'AAA',
Percent = '0.2' ;
Code = 'CCC',
Percent = '0.55'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give you solutions with backtracking. If you really want lists (see note below), you need a predicate that can relate "a list of `A` elements" and "a list of `B` elements" such that each `A`-`B` pair is in some relation.

SWI-Prolog has [maplist/N](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist%2F3) for this:

```
predicate1(Codes, Percents) :-
    findall(Code, (values1(Code, _, Value), Value > 1000), Codes),
    maplist(values2, Codes, Percents).
```

This gives you your codes and an equal length list of the corresponding percentages:

```
?- predicate1(Codes, Percents).
Codes = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'CCC'],
Percents = ['0.2', '0.25', '0.25', '0.55', '0.98', '0.2', '0.55'].
```

**Note:** Prolog beginners love collecting solutions into lists. This is *often* not the best way to solve a problem in Prolog. Backtracking can be more natural, simpler, and more efficient. I recommend that you try to resist the urge to collect everything into lists unless *really* needed.

**Edit:** As a note on style, if I do use `findall/3`, `setof/3`, or `bagof/3`, I prefer to write an auxiliary predicate that hides all variables that are not relevant to the data I want to collect:

```
code_above(Code, Limit) :-
    values1(Code, _, Value),
    Value > Limit.
```

This way the `findall` and `setof` calls look the same, which makes it easy to switch between them. They are also (in my opinion) a lot more readable than the `Value^Date^` gymnastics that `setof` otherwise requires, as illustrated in David Tonhofer's answer:

```
predicate1(Codes, Percents) :- 
    findall(Code, code_above(Code, 1000), Codes),
    maplist(values2, Codes, Percents).

predicate2(Codes, Percents) :- 
    setof(Code, code_above(Code, 1000), Codes),
    maplist(values2, Codes, Percents).
```

With this you get rid of duplicates for free:

```
?- predicate1(Codes, Percents).
Codes = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'CCC'],
Percents = ['0.2', '0.25', '0.25', '0.55', '0.98', '0.2', '0.55'].

?- predicate2(Codes, Percents).
Codes = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'],
Percents = ['0.2', '0.25', '0.55', '0.98'].
```

Comment: ok, maplist works for two fact values, but what about if values2 have more values that i don't use? Example: ```values2(Code, Percent, X, Y, Z)```. I don't care X, Y and Z. I'm tried with maplist(values2, Code, Percent, _, _, _).``` but it's giving an error

Comment: You can define your own as `maplist(_Goal, [], [], [], [], []). maplist(Goal, [A|As], [B|Bs], [C|Cs], [D|Ds], [E|Es]) :- call(Goal, A, B, C, D, E), maplist(Goal, As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es).`, adding as many more `Fs`, `Gs`, ... as you need.